# cmake find_package script failing only Linux

Tags: cmake

I wrote a package finding module for the [Stanford Network Analysis Platform](http://snap.stanford.edu/) (SNAP), which works as expected on macOS but fails on Linux, for some reason it reports not finding Snap despite having apparently located the relevant paths/files.

`FindSnap.cmake`:

```
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
set(Snap_ROOT_DIR $ENV{WORKSPACE_ROOT}/opt/Snap)
message(STATUS "Snap_ROOT_DIR: " ${Snap_ROOT_DIR})

find_path(Snap_CORE
        NAMES "Snap.h"
        PATH_SUFFIXES snap-core
        HINTS ${Snap_ROOT_DIR}
        DOC "The Snap include directory")
message(STATUS "Snap core: " ${Snap_CORE})

find_path(Snap_GLIB_CORE
        NAMES "base.h"
        PATH_SUFFIXES glib-core
        HINTS ${Snap_ROOT_DIR}
        DOC "The Snap GLib include directory")
message(STATUS "Glib core: " ${Snap_GLIB_CORE})

find_library(Snap_LIBRARY
        NAMES libsnap.a
        HINTS ${Snap_ROOT_DIR}/snap-core
        DOC "The Snap library")
message(STATUS "Snap Library: " ${Snap_LIBRARY})

find_package_handle_standard_args(Snap_FOUND DEFAULT_MSG
        Snap_CORE
        Snap_GLIB_CORE
        Snap_LIBRARY)

if (Snap_FOUND)
    set(Snap_LIBRARIES ${Snap_LIBRARY})
    set(Snap_INCLUDE_DIRS ${Snap_CORE} ${Snap_GLIB_CORE})
    set(Snap_DEFINITIONS)
    message(STATUS "Snap Found: " ${Snap_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Package Snap not found")
endif (Snap_FOUND)

mark_as_advanced(Snap_ROOT_DIR Snap_INCLUDE_DIR Snap_LIBRARY)
```

On macOS, Snap is installed in `/opt/Snap`, and this script gets invoked from `CMakeLists.txt` with `find_package(Snap REQUIRED)`. On macOS, this works perfectly, however on Ubuntu, the script reports that Snap is not found, even though the paths `Snap_CORE`, `Snap_GLIB_CORE`, and `Snap_LIBRARY` appear to have been located. On mac I am using cmake version 3.10.2 and on Linux I have tried both versions 2.8 and 3.9, and still I have the same error.

Since I cannot modify `/opt` on the Linux machine, I have installed Snap elsewhere and modified the Snap root directory on the second line as:

```
set(Snap_ROOT_DIR $ENV{WORKSPACE_ROOT}/elsewhere/Snap)
```

The error given on the Linux machine:

```
-- Snap_ROOT_DIR: /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/jdeaton/repos/snap
-- Snap core: /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/jdeaton/repos/snap/snap-core
-- Glib core: /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/jdeaton/repos/snap/glib-core
-- Snap Library: /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/jdeaton/repos/snap/snap-core/libsnap.a
-- Found Snap_FOUND: /afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/jdeaton/repos/snap/snap-core
CMake Error at cmake/FindSnap.cmake:43 (message):
  Package Snap not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

It seems like this should work fine, but somehow it is not working, and only fails on Linux.

Thank you!

Comment: You current description of script results is somehow unclear. Provide exact output of the script.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Good point. I have added the exact output.

Comment: Hm, output `Found Snap_FOUND` looks very weird. It should be `Found Snap`. Didn't you tried to pass `Snap_FOUND` as the first argument to `find_package_handle_standard_args`? Have you tried to clear the cache (remove `CMakeCache.txt` from build directory)?

Comment: Oh my gosh. That was totally it. I was passing `Snap_FOUND` instead of `Snap`. Changing that completely fixed the problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help. If it was actually a typo, feel free to delete the question - typos are hardly googled, so the question is unlikely to help others. But if you assume that someone else may incorrectly read the documentation, and intentionally use `_FOUND` suffix for the first argument, then the question would be useful.

Comment: Alright. I'm not really sure why this happened to be honest. This was my first time writing a script like this so I'm not sure how or why I tried the `Snap_FOUND` argument in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `find_package_handle_standard_args` should be `Snap` instead of `Snap_FOUND`.

```
 find_package_handle_standard_args(Snap DEFAULT_MSG
    Snap_CORE
    Snap_GLIB_CORE
    Snap_LIBRARY)
```